# Need to write the contents on next column of file for elif condition result?

Tags: python

I am reading from a file and checking the numbers in the second column. I have perform the following checks:

- Number is less than 0.20
- Number is less than 0.30
- Number is less than 0.40
- Number is less than 0.50

If condition one is true write the value which satisfies the condition as the first column in an output file.

If condition two is true write the which satisfies the condition as the second column in the same output file.

If condition three is true write the value which satisfies the condition as colunm3 in the the same output file.

If condition four is true write the value which satisfies the condition as colunm4 in the the same output file.

This is what I have so far:

```
  f = open('outfilename','r')
  d = open('newfile','w')
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
  job = line.split()
  if(float(job[2]) < 0.20):
     d.write(str(job[2]))
     d.write('\n')
  elif(float(job[2]) < 0.30):
     d.write(str(job[2]))
     d.write('\n')
  elif(float(job[2]) < 0.40):
     d.write(str(job[2]))
     d.write('\n')
  elif(float(job[2]) < 0.50):
     d.write(str(job[2]))
     d.write('\n')

  d.close()
  f.close()
```

But I am getting this output:

```
 0.061
 0.0
 0.012
 0.0
 0.079
 0.03
 0.109
 0.044
 0.019
 0.035
 0.018
 0.019
 0.004
 0.147
 0.111
 0.184
 0.121
 0.005
 0.299
 0.091
 0.077
 0.245
 0.345
 0.323
 0.456
 0.399
 0.499
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You could use a tempString and add your columns in every `if` statement and at the end, write that tempString to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like below:

```
f = open('outfilename','r')
d = open('newfile','w')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
job = float(line.split()[2])
if(job < 0.20):
   d.write(str(job) + "\t\t\t\n")
elif(job < 0.30):
   d.write("\t" + str(job) + "\t\t\n")
elif(job < 0.40):
   d.write("\t\t" + str(job) + "\t\n")
elif(job < 0.50):
   d.write("\t\t\t" + str(job) + "\n")

d.close()
f.close()
```

The `\t` is the tab character, it introduces a tab space for each of the unused column above

Edit: If you want to print for all columns, as already mentioned in comments, you will need to maintain a string

```
f = open('outfilename','r')
d = open('newfile','w')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    job = float(line.split()[2])
    output = "
    output = output + str(job) +"\t" if job < .2 else output + "\t\t"
    output = output + str(job) +"\t" if job < .3 else output + "\t\t"
    output = output + str(job) +"\t" if job < .4 else output + "\t\t"
    output = output + str(job) +"\t" if job < .5 else output + "\t\t"
    d.write(output+"\n")
d.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: @ansh01 the numbers which is <0.20 is also <0.30,<0.40,<0.50 but in this result those numbers are not being printed in 2,3,4th column

Comment: Check the edits. You will need to do something similar to get the output you want. I added an extra `\t` for readability's sake.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more explicit about the column handling - you can choose whether the value is written into all the qualifying columns or just into the first by setting `only_one`

```
f = open('outfilename','r')
d = open('newfile','w')
limits = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

only_first = True

for line in f:
    columns = ['' for l in limits]
    job = float(line.split()[2])
    for i, limit in enumerate(limits):
        if job < limit:
            columns[i] = str(job)
            if only_first: break
    d.write('\t'.join(columns) + '\n')
```